# Isotope with masonry is not filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I would like to ask you for help with filtering option while using Isotope on Wordpress CMS.

I have couple of links to filter the content, whole system is plugged to Wordpress using Advanced Custom Fields Pro as a reapeater, but basically I have pasted the html output.

The whole problem is that I am unable to filter my blocks, but everything else is working fine.

I would be glad for any help!

PHP:

```
function my_masonry(){
    wp_enqueue_script('masonry');
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_masonry');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button-group filters-button-group">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">Pokaż wszystkie</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".Komercyjne">Komercyjne</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".Niekomercyjne">Niekomercyjne</button>
</div>

<div id="container" class="js-masonry">
    <div class="item element-item Wnętrza" data-category="Wnętrza">
        <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item element-item Elewacje" data-category="Elewacje">
        <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div  class="item element-item Komercyjne" data-category="Komercyjne">
        <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div  class="item element-item Niekomercyjne" data-category="Niekomercyjne">
        <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item element-item" data-category="">
        <a href="#"><img class="photo" src="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).load(function($) {
    var $grid = $('#container');
    $grid.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        itemSelector : '.item',
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        },
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 350,
            gutter: 30
        }
    });

    // bind filter button click
    $('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    // change is-checked class on buttons
    $('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );

        $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
          $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
          $(this).addClass('is-checked');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you place some code here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's great that you provided a link to your code, but, I would highly recommend per community guidelines to provide your code directly within your question. Even better, SO has tools that allow you (and those of us looking to answer the question) the ability to see the code running within the question directly. It should help you get a better answer.

Comment: I have edited my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did only two small changes in your code.

First, I've switched your [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event for the [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, which made the isotope plugin initialize.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

After that, inside your click event, I've just changed your var `$container` (which does not exist) for the correct var `$grid` (which contains your container) and everything seems to work now.

Check it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1nh8v6g/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Remember to accept this as the correct answer. Glad that helped!